# How does one build an OpenCL program with multiple .cl sources

Tags: opencl

I am in the process of converting my GPU application that has many CUDA kernels to OpenCL. I am trying to find online with no success on how to build an app using multiple .cl files. I will need to run 1 kernel then hav the outputs of the first go into the 2nd and so on.
Any healp would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you [`clBuildProgram`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clBuildProgram.html) each file into a separate program object?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm a newbie to OpenCL but a veteran to CUDA. I have an app (.cpp files ) that call varius CUDA kernels and I'm trying to map this same schema to how the same thing it could be done in OpenCL.

Comment: All the examples I see run just one kernel

Comment: can those kernels run parallel(no dependency) or sequential (dependent)?

Answer (score 0):

You read the .cl files into a strings at C++ runtime. With multiple files, you have several choices:

1. You can just concatenate the strings of multiple .cl files (in the correct order of course).
2. You can outsource parts of the GPU code in .hcl header files, and in the main .cl source file call #include “header_file.hcl". OpenCL has a preprocessor that at C++ runtime and before OpenCL compile time handles the #include.
3. If your .cl files really are separate entities without any cross-referencing, you can compile them with separate program objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's similar to a single kernel code. Look at the below example:

1. create input and output buffers for kernel-1
2. setKernelArgs and enququeWritedata for kernel-1
3. enqueueNdRange and enqueueReadData the output-1 to host(which will be input to kernel-2)
4. create input and output buffers for kernel-2
5. use the earlier read output-1 to enququeWritedata for kernel-2
6. enqueueNdRange and enqueueReadData the output-2 to host(which will be input to kernel-3)

And goes on...

This is a simpler way to achieve your goal and written with OpenCL 1.2 in mind, however, there could be an easy way in higher versions.